# Keeping checkbox values with gae-sessions

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session

I look for answers but It was all about php. I got this index.html:

```
 <form method="post">       
   <input type="checkbox" name="opts" value="opt1" opt[0]> option 1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="opts" value="opt2" opt[1]> option 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="opts" value="opt3" opt[2]> option 3<br>
  <br>
   <input name="" type="submit" value="Save" >  

</form>
```

and this main.py

```
import webapp2
import cgi
import os
import jinja2
from gaesessions import get_current_session
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        session=get_current_session()
        opt=session.get('opt',[])        jinja_environment=jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates')))
        tpi_vars={"opt":opt}
        template=jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')

        self.response.write(template.render(tpi_vars))

    def post(self):
        opt=self.request.get("opt", allow_multiple=True)
        session=get_current_session()

        session['opt']=opt
```

I want to store checked checkboxes and get them. How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python code seems correct, apart from one weird bug whereby the line using `jinja_environment` is concatenated to the previous one (?!).

Your **Jinja** template seems wrong as it **doesn't** look in the environment, nor does it mark any checkbox as `checked`.  I would recommend something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="opts" value="opt1" {{ops.get('opt1','')}>
    option 1<br>
```

and so on -- the double braces to check into the environment, and a dictionary `ops` that you could prepare on the Python side.

Right now what you get as `opt` is a list such as e.g ['opt1'] if that's the only checked checkbox at post time.  You could deal with that in the Jinja side, but it's easier on the Python side, I think.  So, instead of:

```
tpi_vars={"opt":opt}
```

I'd do:

```
tpi_vars={'ops': dict.fromkeys(opt, 'checked')}
```

Of course, you don't have to do it just before you render the Jinja2 template -- you could do this list-to-dict translation at any time.  But since it **is** about presentation issues, this seems a good place for it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did  tpi_vars={'opts': dict.fromkeys(opts, 'checked')}  and session['opts']=opts  . it seems to work but how can I use them? using like this is a proper way?         if u'opt1' in opts:
            self.response.out.write("opt1 is checked")

Comment: @St3114, no!  In the get you just write the `template.render` as you do now (with modified template and environment as per my A); in the post you get `'opts'` (**not** the typoed `'opt'` as you did) which is just a list of the checkboxes that were left checked as the user submitted the form.  Presumably you mean to use that info for some application-specific purpose, in addition to persisting it to the session -- and you never tell us your application-specific purpose (I doubt the app's purpose is to tell the user which checkboxes they checked, right?-)

Comment: I want to create gae project which will generate rss feed due to selected options. these options will be columnists. I was going to add a login check. user will login and change the options. sitename.appspot.com/rss.xml will be the generated rss. I guess I cant store this settings in a session. it ll only work for same browser. my whole project https://yadi.sk/d/ADwATa7VeNR5m

Comment: @St3114, of course you can store in the session, just make sure the session is backed by the datastore, see docs at http://dound.com/myprojects/gae-sessions/docs/html/docindex.html !  This has nothing at all to do with checkboxes so I suggest you start another question about gaesessions only.